# Symbolism behind Hephaestus riding a donkey

Tags: greek

When Hephaestus returns to Olympus after being thrown out by Hera, some authors/artists portray him as riding a donkey:

[image]

(Source: [Theoi.com](https://www.theoi.com/Gallery/K7.1.html))

Is there any reason why he rides a donkey? Why not a horse or a turtle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Wikipedia (though I cannot confirm), [it is a mule.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hephaestus#cite_ref-27)

A donkey would actually make *more* sense, as Dionysus was the one who helped Hephaestus return to Olympia after his fall ([source](http://www.theoi.com/Olympios/HephaistosMyths.html)), and **the donkey is associated with Dionysus** and his ways, according to *The Book of Symbols* (316).

Comment: What about the rest of the Gods?? Why not just a cow for Hera?

Comment: Hera was the one who cast out Hephaestus to begin with (at least according to one version of the story), so it's doubtful her symbolism would be useful. 
In particular, "Hephaistos refused to listen to any other of the gods save Dionysos", who got him drunk and led him back to Olympus.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, according to [Theoi.com](http://www.theoi.com/Summary/Hephaistos.html), that Hephaestus' animal was a donkey, but nothing on why. My own thought is that it, like Hephaestus, was a worker rather than a warrior.

He may have ridden it on his return to Olympus to show that he came in peace, as [riding a donkey](http://www.gotquestions.org/king-ride-donkey.html) could symbolize peaceful intent.

Answer (score 1):

Hera had once driven Dionysus to go mad. While he searched for a temple of Zeus in which to cure himself, he came upon a large marsh. He was unable in his maddened state to reason his way past it, but two donkeys came along and he rode one across the marsh. Grateful for the donkey's help, he gave it a voice with which to speak. Silenus, the foster father of Dionysus, thereafter rode the talking donkey on their travels. Dionysus is typically depicted riding a leopard, whereas Hephaestus is shown riding a donkey (see Poeticon Astronomicon, pp. 62-63).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).